# How to do Non Interactive User Login from browser for SAML SSO flow between IDP and SP

Tags: saml-2.0

I am unable to find Api's on implementing SAML authentication flow for the SP Application programmatically without user's to manually enter their credentials on SAML compliant IDP( SAP IAS) login screen configured for the SP application as a starting point , I have established the trust between the the IDP and SP application ,trying to implement non interactive login from browser , is there any way to implement this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the saml standards you can't send password via saml authn request, therefore you will not be able to authenticate from idp without redirecting to idp login using saml. But if you have control over idp you can implement a shared cookie concept to achve this requirement, but then this is no more saml compliant.

Answer (score 1):

SAML was never designed for machine-to-machine authorization. The closest (IMO) that you can safely get while staying inside intended usage and specs is passing a SAML assertion wrapped in a WS-Trust STS transaction.

I would suggest you look into either WS-Trust or OAuth. Either of these are built for machine-to-machine transactions.

Comment: Thanks Andrew and Darshani for your replies .